# How to change UITableview's array content from a dictionary input?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have many different arrays with dictionaries of hotels in a data model class. For example, the array `madridHotels` would hold dictionaries of hotels in Madrid. To list these hotels in a tableview, I use a method called `madridHotelsCount` in my dataModel class:

```
-(int)madridHotelsCount {
return self.madridHotels.count;
}
```

In a tableview's `numberOfRowsInSection` method, I would put

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView*)theTableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return [self.dataModel madridHotelsCount];
}
```

in order to list the hotels in Madrid. This works just fine. But since I have about 20 cities, I have a feeling that having 20 different VC's and XIB's to make city-based tableviews is plain stupid and wasteful.

In my "Select City" tableview, each city has a key called `cityString` with the appropriate string meant for the "Hotels in City X" tableview. In Madrid's case, for example, the string would be `madridHotelsCount`. If I'm not mistaken there is a way to use this information when pushing the "Hotels in City X" tableview controller.

What I can't figure out is how to change the string `madridHotelsCount` in the tableview method with, for example, `barcelonaHotelsCount` depending on a key in a "Select City" tableview so that I can only use one VC and XIB.

Hope this makes sense...

Comment: Does `dataModel` contain an array for each hotel? If so you may wish to structure that class slightly better?

Comment: Yes. In `dataModel`, I have an array with all hotels called `hotels`. Then, I have 20 different arrays with hotels for different cities (which are copies of the hotels array, filtered according to city). I think this structure is pretty sound, but any other approaches are welcome!

Comment: This sounds very unscaleable every time you add a new city you need to add a new ivar as well. Use an `NSDictionary` with the keys being the cities and then the values being the `NSArray`'s of hotels

Comment: Thanks, Paul.s. Could you expand on your approach a little more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the data structure in `dataModel` to use

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *citiesHotels;
```

The cities are the keys and the values are the arrays of hotels.

An example might be like

```
NSArray *madrid = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"madridHotelA", @"madridHotelB", nil];
NSArray *barcelona = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"barcelonaHotelA", @"barcelonaHotelB", nil];

NSDictionary *citiesHotels = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:madrid, @"Madrid", barcelona, @"barcelona", nil];

[madrid release]; madrid = nil;
[barcelona release]; barcelona = nil;

self.citiesHotels = citiesHotels;

[citiesHotels release]; citiesHotels= nil;
```

Add a method to the model like this

```
- (NSInteger)hotelCountForCity:(NSString *)city
{
    int count = 0;

    NSArray *hotels = [self.citiesHotels valueForKey:city];

    if (hotels) {
        count = [hotels count];
    }

    return count;
}
```

To get the hotel you would need something like this in your model

```
- (Hotel *)hotelAtIndex:(NSInteger)index forCity:(NSString *)city
{
    NSArray * hotels = [self.citiesHotels valueForKey:city];
    return [hotels objectAtIndex:index];
}
```

These are called like this

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView*)theTableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    return [self.dataModel hotelCountForCity:theSelectedCityName];
}
```

And in `cellForRowAtIndexPath you do

```
Hotel *hotel = [self.dataModel hotelAtIndex:indexPath.row forCity:theSelectedCity];
```

Comment: whoa... I'm starting to understand what you're saying. Let me get my mind around this. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: In the tableview's `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, I call `Hotel* hotel = [self.dataModel hotelAtIndex:indexPath.row];`. The method is described in the dataModel as: `(Hotel*)hotelAtIndex:(int)index {return [self.hotels objectAtIndex:index];`. How would one reconcile your approach with this method? I can't see how I can have a `hotel`  object available. Sorry, but I should of mentioned this in my original question...

Comment: Thanks! I can see how this can work. Just one question: how do I call the 2 methods in `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` based on your methods? I'm still new to this game so you'll have to excuse my boneheadedness!

Comment: One last question just to clear some confusion on my side: do I need to manually state `theSelectedCityName` and `theSelectedCity` in the tableview? I'm hoping not! More boneheadedness, I'm afraid.

Comment: On the TableViewController where you select the city you would instantiate the hotels TableViewController in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. Instantiate the hotels controller and pass it the cityName that was selected. This is the value you use where I out `theSelectedCity`

Comment: Stupid question: how do I pass the cityName that was selected to the hotels TableViewController? Like this? `NSDictionary *dictionary = [self.dataModel objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` `HotelsViewController *hvc = [[HotelsViewController alloc] initwithNibName:@"HotelsViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];` `hvc.city = [dictionary objectForKey:@"city"];` `[self.navigationController pushViewController:hvc animated:YES];` `[hvc release];` Is this correct? In this way, can I pass the city name value to the hotels TableViewController and populate `theSelectedCity` in both method?

Answer (score 2):

You need to change it to something like this so you pass the hotel to each view.

```
-(int)hotelCountForCity:(NSString *)cityName
```

I would rewrite it so it was more generic as you shouldn't be repeating yourself like that.

although its not the best way, but if all that code is already there, you can..

```
NSString city = @"madrid";
SEL selector = selectorFromString([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@HotelsCount", city]);
int count = 0;
if([self respondsToSelector:selector])
{
     int *count = [self performSelector:selector];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, bigkm. In your example, would I use it like `return [self.dataModel hotelCountForCity];`? If so, how would I get `cityName`?

Comment: Sorry, I commented before your post was finished... let me study it.

Comment: That seems pretty nasty and not very OO. I would encourage rewriting the class now. I think you was onto a winner before the selector stuff.  Maybe restructuring the data model to use an `NSDictionary` with the keys being cityNames and the values being the `NSArray`'s of hotels